# Performance or performances?

Tags: grammar

Is the correct term, "well done to the English on their performance or performances."?

I believe "performance" to be the correct choice.

Comment: Please explain your question further. What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if it was a single group/team performance or several individual performances.

We often consider group nouns to be plural ("The police scrambled for their cars.") when each member of the group is acting independently. However, if the group is acting as a single unit, we can consider it to be a single entity ("The team's first goal occurred in the second half.")